# Convert json file without headers into csv

Tags: python, json, csv

I am converting json file into a csv file. json file does not have a header. It fails with the error `'unicode' object has no attribute 'values'`.

Since there is no header, it's failing on: `csvwriter.writerow(row.values())`.

**json** file without the header:

```
{"ababab": "Complex numbers", "s1234": "Scatterplots"}
```

**Python code:**

```
csv_output_path = output_path + "skill_names_" + str(report_date) + ".csv"
    #print(jsonoutput_path)

with open(local_path + filename) as f:
    data = json.load(f)
    print(data)

 # open file for writing
cd_skill_data = open(csv_output_path, 'w')

#create header for csv
csvwriter = csv.writer(cd_skill_data, delimiter=',')

for row in data:
    csvwriter.writerow(row.values())


cd_skill_data.close()
```

Comment: Have you done **any** debugging at all? what do you imagine `for row in data:` is doing? Have you tried printing `row`? It's not doing what you think it is doing. Even if it was, you are on Python 2, so `dict.values` will not guarantee any order, so your approach is fundamentally flawed.

Comment: You say it's failing in two different places — which makes little sense...

Comment: what is the desired output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`data` is a dict.  When you loop through a dict, you loop through its keys.  So in your loop, `row` equals "ababab", then "s1234".

It's really hard to say whether your code or data is wrong here.  The code wants a list of dicts.  The data is a single dict (or in JSON terms, "object").

If you want a list of dicts, update your data by putting square brackets at the start and end.  If you want a single dict, then you need to handle the data as-is, e.g. iterating through `data.items()`.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, Aaron. Yes, the data is in a single dict. Below code worked: 
                                                                                                                     
    for key, value in data.items():
        print([key, value])
        csvwriter.writerow([key, value])

Answer (score 0):

```
# Import Libraries
import pandas as pd
import json
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize

# Read Json file
myjson = {"ababab": "Complex numbers", "s1234": "Scatterplots"}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(json_normalize(myjson))
print df2.head(10)

# Export Json to CSV
df2.to_csv('C:/your_path/new_table.csv',encoding='utf-8', index=False, header=False)
```